# Should the verb "impact" be always followed by "on"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Nowadays, we often see the word *impact* being used as a verb. My question is, should  it be always followed by the preposition *on*? Oxford Dictionaries gives the following example:

> The cuts will inevitably impact on service delivery.

I saw elsewhere this sentence:

> The author offers policies that unduly impact certain populations.

Is there any thumbrule for this?

Comment: Your first example is not idiomatic.

Comment: No.  For example:  `The meteor will impact the Earth soon.`

Comment: `The cuts will inevitably impact on service delivery` is incorrect.  `The cuts will inevitably **have an** impact on service delivery` is the correct grammar.  Also, `The cuts will inevitably **have a negative** impact on service delivery.`

Comment: Read Peter Shor's comment.  Whether it's idiomatic or not depends on whether you're GB or US.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily.  The sentence you've quoted is perfectly correct as well.

Here are some sentences I've dug up where *impact* isn't followed by *on*:

> *Both events negatively impacted her life.*

[from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impact)

> *The book discusses the impact of Christian thinking on western society.*

[from Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impact)

> *...the potential for women to impact the political process.*

[from Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/impact)

As far as I can see, your definition of *impact* (verb) can be used in four different ways: ([from Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/impact)):

**VERB +** on/upon

as in

> *Such schemes mean little unless they impact on people.*

**VERB** on/upon noun

as in

> *The reduction in the number of days that Parliament sat would impact on the quality of its work.*

**VERB** noun

as in

> *...the potential for women to impact the political process.* (mentioned
>   before)

verb-link **ADJECTIVE**

as in

> *Trading is being increasingly impacted by the current recession.*

Hope I've helped!

Comment: In the Cambridge Dictionary example, *impact* **is** followed by *on*.

Comment: Not if you go to 'more examples' then look at the last one.

Comment: *Impact* **is** followed by *on* in **the** example quoted in this answer: ' . . . the impact . . . on western society'.

Comment: But impact of ......... on is different, as it is not a direct impact on, which is what the OP asked for.  It's just another way of saying it.

Comment: In your second example "impact" is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: Oh!  You are correct.  But you can still tell what I mean, which is why I used three examples.

Comment: The fact that the noun is used in your second example **is** significant; it's unhelpful to include it as it muddies the waters. // Also, Lordology,  'Trading is being increasingly impacted by the current recession' is the passive form of 'The current recession is increasingly impacting trading.' [verb]-[nominal {ing-form}].

Answer (score 4):

Your first example is not idiomatic.  If you use "impact" as a verb, the object of the verb (the thing impacted) needs no "on".  If you use "impact" as a noun, however, you need the preposition.

Comment: Whether you think it's idiomatic might depend on which side of the pond you live on. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+impact+the%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cwill+impact+the%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cwill+impact+on+the%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cwill+impact+on+the%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20impact%20the%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20impact%20the%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20impact%20on%20the%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20impact%20on%20the%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: ... and my Ngram seems to show that some elderly prescriptivists would argue that *impact* shouldn't be used as a verb at all (even though the OED says that it was first used as a verb around 1600, nearly 200 years before it was first used as a noun).

Comment: @PeterShor is right.  Also see https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-33223503

Answer (score 1):

Impact will be followed by 'on' if it is a noun. This circumstance will have an impact to my life.
However,it should not be followed by 'on' if it is verb. This circumstance impacts my lifestyle.

Comment: Impact will be followed by 'on' if it is a noun. For ex.: This circumstance will have an impact to my life. However,it should not be followed by 'on' if it is verb. For ex.: This circumstance impacts my lifestyle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should edit the original answer rather than posting substantially the same answer again.

Comment: Your answer lacks impact (and also supporting argument or authority). My sentence lacks “on”, although it is quite grammatical and I am using “impact” as a noun. Please read the Help on answering questions.

Comment: I am new here, so I am not allowed to comment directly to David's comment to Ricky. Let's examine this more closely. Your answer (subject) lacks (verb) impact (object). While this is grammatically accurate, the object is unidentified. If it is identified, then on (or another preposition) is required: Your answer lacks impact on the discussion. Ricky's answer is accurate. Whether the word impact is currently being overused is another topic.
https://style.mla.org/impact-as-a-verb/

Comment: Please don't use answers to comment on other responses. Answers should only be used to directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Nowadays, we often see the word impact being used as a verb.

It has been a verb since the 17th century.

1601   P. Holland tr. Pliny History of the World II. xx. xxi. 73   *The seed of this hearbe remooveth the tough humours bedded in the stomacke, how hard impacted soever they be.*

1677   T. Gale Court of Gentiles: Pt. IV iv. Proem 4   *Ideas or notions impacted on the mind.*

> Should the verb "impact" be always followed by "on"?

No.

1897   T. C. Allbutt et al. Syst. Med. III. 835   A stone-like mass..which had become impacted **in** the lower ilium.

1929   ‘Seamark’ Down River vi. 172   *Something impacted **with** a soft thud **against** Lingard's temple.*

1962   F. I. Ordway et al. Basic Astronautics v. 201   *The Soviet Lunnaya Raketa was launched early in the afternoon of September 12,
1959 and impacted **onto** the Moon's surface just after midnight on September 14, Moscow time.*